# Subprocess.Call can't/won't access D:

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, drive

I'm currently trying to get Python to run an .exe from D:/My Games using Subprocess. The purpose is simple, just run the game selected. The code I'm working with now, works, when I try accessing my C: drive but I get an error when trying to access my D: drive.
"Error Table Out of Range" is the error I get. 
Anyone know how to be able to access this drive from within Python?

```
import wx
import subprocess
import os

GamesList=(os.listdir('D:\\My Games\\'))
for item in GamesList:
    if str(item) == 'desktop.ini':
        GamesList.remove(item)

class MainMenu(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Games List", size=(550,400))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        GameBox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1,(407,5),(122,350),GamesList,wx.LB_SINGLE)
        GameBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, OnGameSelection)

def OnGameSelection(Event):
    GameBox = Event.GetEventObject()
    GameIndex = GameBox.GetSelection()
    SelGame = GamesList[GameIndex]
    subprocess.call(['D:\\My Games\\'+ SelGame + '\\' + SelGame + '.exe'])


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=MainMenu(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Have you tried running other programs from your D: drive?   E.g. try copying notepad.exe to D: and running it from there.  As for your error message, are you trying to run 'Tomb Raider: Anniversary' on Windows 7, by any chance?  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-gaming/get-an-error-error-out-of-table-range-when-trying/c7acbfc2-788e-4552-9bb7-42b6e5d83b20

Comment: That's funny, I am trying to run Tomb Raider for the testing. (Win 8)

Comment: You were right. I can run Dishonored perfectly. I'm looking in to fixing Tomb Raiders issues now. Thanks.